# How to put brackets into $10^2÷10÷10÷10÷10 = 10$ to make it correct?

Tags: arithmetic

My son was given a [challenge division sheet](http://jpsyearsix.weebly.com/uploads/2/0/4/4/20442177/t3_week_5_maths_mrs_arnold-webb_main_group.pdf) to be done during a school lesson.

He said he struggled for ages with question 14:

> Put brackets into this expression to make it correct.
>
> $10^2 ÷ 10 ÷ 10 ÷ 10 ÷ 10 = 10$

I tried to help but I could not see any way to make this work - it seems you will always end up with an even power of 10 on the left hand side.  Can anyone tell us what we are missing?

Comment: Here is a stupid answer: $(10^2 ÷ 10 ÷ 10 ÷ 10 ÷ 1)(0) = (1)(0)$. I agree that the "even power of 10" issue is going to be difficult without some trick.

Comment: Probably a typo in the problem set.

Comment: Maybe assuming $() \equiv 0$...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**NOTE:** This answer assumes cheating, like putting brackets in between digits isn't allowed.

There's a reason why you always get and even power of $10$ on the LHS. Note that by putting brackets on the LHS you actually decide whether you will divide or multiply the product up to that point with $10$. As you have $4$ $10$'s on the LHS you will have the same parity of $10$'s dividing and multiplying $10^2$, as $4$ is an even number. Eventually you will multiply $10^2$ with an even power of $10$. So no matter what, when you multiply/divide an even power with an even power you will get an even power. So eventually the LHS will be an even power of $10$ meaning this question is impossible to solve.

Answer (score 4):

You can put a single bracket over the equals sign so that it looks a bit like this:

$$10^2÷10÷10÷10÷10 \neq 10$$

Answer (score 3):

$$0=1(0^2)÷10÷10÷10÷10=1(0)=0$$

This assuming that, as it usually is, multiplication is implicitly assumed; $1(0)=1\times 0$.

Answer (score 0):

You just calculate the whole thing, but instead of multiplying or dividing by ten, you count the powers of ten and you add or subtract them, so you get:

$$ 2 ± 1 ± 1 ± 1 ± 1 = 1$$

Now check what happens with the parity of the result, when you are adding or subtracting one:

$2$ : parity : even
$2± 1$ : parity : odd
$2± 1 ± 1$ : parity : even
$2± 1 ± 1 ± 1$ : parity : even
$2± 1 ± 1 ± 1 ± 1$ : parity : even

And as an $1$ (the final result) is not even, you can see that it's impossible to get this result.